# How can I resolve an AssemblyName to an assembly file path without loading that assembly?

Tags: .net, system.reflection, assembly-resolution, assembly-loading

Is there any public API in the .NET Framework, in .NET Core, or in .NET Standard that can resolve a `System.Reflection.AssemblyName` to a file path of the assembly file that would be loaded, *without actually loading* that assembly?

The best I've currently got is this:

```cs
string ResolveToPath(AssemblyName name) => Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad(name).Location;
```

But that still causes the assembly to be loaded (albeit only into the reflection-only context).

(Assume that I do not want to change the way how the runtime locates assemblies. I'm asking this for use in a library, where I am not free to inspect application configuration files, defining an `AppDomain.AssemblyResolve` handler, etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Candidate APIs in the framework:

- [**`AssemblyDependencyResolver` in System.Runtime.Loader**](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Runtime/Loader/AssemblyDependencyResolver.cs) having a method `string ResolveAssemblyToPath(AssemblyName assemblyName)`, which is currently only available on .NET Core.
- **System.Reflection.MetadataLoadContext** ([source on GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/tree/master/src/System.Reflection.MetadataLoadContext), [package on nuget.org](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Reflection.MetadataLoadContext)), which apparently faces the exact same problem: being able to retrieve an `Assembly` from an `AssemblyName`, which obviously requires loading the former from somewhere.

  The creators of that library have externalized this problem by requiring the programmer to provide a `MetadataLoadContext` with a [`MetadataAssemblyResolver`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Reflection.MetadataLoadContext/src/System/Reflection/MetadataAssemblyResolver.cs) dependency that does that work for it.

  While this library comes with a single concrete implementation ([`PathAssemblyResolver`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Reflection.MetadataLoadContext/src/System/Reflection/PathAssemblyResolver.cs)), it does *not* provide an implementation that encapsulates the runtime's native assembly probing/resolution algorithm.

#### How do other libraries outside the framework deal with assembly resolution?

- **Mono.Cecil** models assembly resolution with its [`IAssemblyResolver` abstraction](https://github.com/jbevain/cecil/blob/1b79b96d29f1e8e9ba832191b1b42ea9cb750d20/Mono.Cecil/MetadataResolver.cs#L17-L20) and has a base implementation in the [`BaseAssemblyResolver` class](https://github.com/jbevain/cecil/blob/master/Mono.Cecil/BaseAssemblyResolver.cs).
- **Roslyn** has a [`MetadataReferenceResolver` abstraction](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/357fa7e9dc82e5c8c2ca49e3033362e90ac9f287/src/Compilers/Core/Portable/MetadataReference/MetadataReferenceResolver.cs) which is implemented in e.g. the [`RuntimeMetadataReferenceResolver` class](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/357fa7e9dc82e5c8c2ca49e3033362e90ac9f287/src/Scripting/Core/Hosting/Resolvers/RuntimeMetadataReferenceResolver.cs).

  (I found out about this via [the blog post "Referencing system assemblies in Roslyn compilations" by Luís Gonçalves](https://luisfsgoncalves.wordpress.com/2017/03/20/referencing-system-assemblies-in-roslyn-compilations/) and [this GitHub post by @tmat](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/16846#issuecomment-276443112).)

#### Some platform-specific pointers

- **.NET Core**: On .NET Core, both of the above libraries appear to rely on the `TRUSTED_PLATFORM_ASSEMBLIES` data property in `AppContext`, which is documented in ["Write a custom .NET Core host to control the .NET runtime from your native code"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/netcore-hosting). There's also an `APP_PATH` data property that could be used for probing.
- **.NET Framework:** The assembly resolution algorithm is described in ["How the Runtime Locates Assemblies"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/deployment/how-the-runtime-locates-assemblies). I was hoping that the framework would expose that algorithm with an API (it doesn't), but at least the algorithm can be reproduced given this information.